# Is there a way to download the weekly users CSV file for a web extension from the Google Webstore Dashboard?

Tags: google-api, chrome-web-store

In the Google Webstore Dashboard you can view weekly users on a graph, just below it gives you an option to export the data as a CSV file. Is there currently an API that allows you to do this programmatically? If not, what's the best way to either, request an API be created, or request the CSV file via an http request?